What should be `Good Enough` requirement for Substrate based chain?
I am working on a Substrate based chain. I want to make sure my chain is up to par for Polkadot community.
For example: my chain should use latest Polkadot SDK stable version.
Are there other things, which I should take care of to make chain up to par for the community?

A few I could think about on the top of my head.
Keep all private keys secure and private.
Decide on sudo or governance for maintenance.
You should also make sure you have ran benchmarks and integrated all weights. If the costs of different extrinsics are not aligned with each other there could be the possibility of a denial of service attack.
